# Trigger function can't update table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Here is my trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_table_insert()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'id is null';
    END IF;
    UPDATE e_sub_agreement SET ro_id = NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_table_insert AFTER INSERT ON e_sub_agreement FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_table_insert();
```

The problem is that it doesn't update table e_sub_agreement. I checked NEW value and everything is good. It returns with the new id. If I change where statement id = "some existing id in table", then it works. It changes ro_id to the new id. How is it possible? My guess is that data has not been inserted into table and trigger function can't find row with the given id. But it's not how trigger's after insert function works. What's the magic?

Comment: Add table definition to the question. Also an example of the INSERT query you are using.

Comment: Your trigger uses simple assignment to change the value `new.ro_id`. However an `after trigger` cannot do that. The reference you used ( dbfiddle.uk/Wpkms9ne ) uses an actual `update` statement. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q7sT1Obo) showing differences between Before/After and Assignment/Update. Note that only *assignment of ro_id* in after update trigger failed; assignment in before trigger and ddl after trigger succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

An AFTER trigger can not change anything. Running an additional UPDATE is also quite inefficient. Change this to a BEFORE trigger and assign the value you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_table_insert()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'id is null';
  END IF;
  NEW.ro_id := NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_table_insert 
  BEFORE INSERT ON e_sub_agreement 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_table_insert();
```

Note that the NOT NULL check is better done by defining the column  as NOT NULL.

Comment: But that's the main point, I want to change column value with new id. And that's why it should be nullable. After insert it changes value to the generated id. I've been using after trigger always. And it works like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210560/update-column-of-a-inserted-row-with-with-its-generated-id-in-a-single-query here is suggested using after trigger also. I tried your way with before trigger, still no effect. It doesn't want to change anything at all

Comment: Well, if you want to change a column in the just inserted row, a BEFORE trigger is the most efficient solution. Why should `id` be nullable when you want to update `ro_id`? The trigger most certainly works: https://dbfiddle.uk/Wpkms9ne

Comment: not id, I mean ro_id should be nullable. Sorry, some misunderstanding happened). The same works with after insert https://dbfiddle.uk/0qtVa4ss. But it seems like I have some kind of problems in my code. Cause nor before nor after trigger doesn't apply changes

Comment: So the check for `new.id is null` is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: agree on that. how is it possible that new data is inserted, but trigger function can't find it? as I know it should be running in one transaction? but now, it's like insert data on e_sub_agreement -> update trigger (can't find data) -> insert data on e_sub_agreement

Comment: @Belayer I am using a BEFORE trigger in my answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, placement incorrect, intended for OP. Moved